# Connect to Watson Speech-to-Text API using websockets for real-time transcription

Tags: python, r, websocket, speech-recognition, ibm-watson

I am trying to write a script to call the Watson Speech-to-Text (STT) API to continually transcribe speech being recorded through a microphone word-for-word in real-time. I read that this should be possible using the Websockets version of the API.

I have a Python script that should be able to do this on Linux (assuming the dependencies are installed), however, it does not work on Mac OS X.

```
from ws4py.client.threadedclient import WebSocketClient
import base64, json, ssl, subprocess, threading, time

class SpeechToTextClient(WebSocketClient):
    def __init__(self):
        ws_url = "wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"

        username = "your username"
        password = "your password"
        auth_string = "%s:%s" % (username, password)
        base64string = base64.encodestring(auth_string).replace("\n", "")

        self.listening = False

        try:
            WebSocketClient.__init__(self, ws_url,
                headers=[("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)])
            self.connect()
        except: print "Failed to open WebSocket."

    def opened(self):
        self.send('{"action": "start", "content-type": "audio/l16;rate=16000"}')
        self.stream_audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.stream_audio)
        self.stream_audio_thread.start()

    def received_message(self, message):
        message = json.loads(str(message))
        if "state" in message:
            if message["state"] == "listening":
                self.listening = True
        print "Message received: " + str(message)

    def stream_audio(self):
        while not self.listening:
            time.sleep(0.1)

        reccmd = ["arecord", "-f", "S16_LE", "-r", "16000", "-t", "raw"]
        p = subprocess.Popen(reccmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        while self.listening:
            data = p.stdout.read(1024)

            try: self.send(bytearray(data), binary=True)
            except ssl.SSLError: pass

        p.kill()

    def close(self):
        self.listening = False
        self.stream_audio_thread.join()
        WebSocketClient.close(self)

try:
    stt_client = SpeechToTextClient()
    raw_input()
finally:
    stt_client.close()
```

Ideally, I wouldn't even be doing this in Python, but R, which is my native language which I will have to transfer the results back to to be processed anyway.

Could anyone provide me with a solution for how I can get a streamed transcription?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answer is exactly what you want, but sounds like an issue with the parameter `continuous`.

As you can see, has the lib [Python SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk) inside Watson-developer-cloud.

You can install with: `pip install watson-developer-cloud`

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1

speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    username='YOUR SERVICE USERNAME',
    password='YOUR SERVICE PASSWORD',
    x_watson_learning_opt_out=False
)

print(json.dumps(speech_to_text.models(), indent=2))

print(json.dumps(speech_to_text.get_model('en-US_BroadbandModel'), indent=2))

with open(join(dirname(__file__), '../resources/speech.wav'),
          'rb') as audio_file:
data = json.dumps(speech_to_text.recognize(audio_file, content_type='audio/wav', timestamps=False, word_confidence=False, continuous=True), indent=2)
print(data)
```

**Obs.:** The service returns an `array` of results with one per utterance.

In the line [#L44](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/watson_developer_cloud/speech_to_text_v1.py#L44), has the `params` that you can use, so, for continuous transcription, you need to use the parameter `continuous` and set to `true` like the example above.

- See the [Official Documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/websockets.html#WSkeep) talking about Websockets for keeping the connection alive. (Maybe this is what you need).

Answer (score -1):

For some good examples of how to do this using R, check out these great blog posts by Ryan Anderson.

- [Voice Controlled Music Machine](https://dreamtolearn.com/ryan/r_journey_to_watson/50)
- [Python as a tool to help with Continuous Audio](https://dreamtolearn.com/ryan/r_journey_to_watson/42) - This shows how you can use R for your main logic, and use Python to deal with handling just the audio.

Ryan has done a lot of work with R and the Watson API's - he shares a lot of his knowledge on his [blog](https://dreamtolearn.com/ryan/r_journey_to_watson).